# How to convert integer sizes and pointer declarations from C++ to Python?

Tags: python, c++, pointers, integer, size

I am trying to convert this C++ function into Python code but I am having trouble in doing so for the pointer and turning the python variables into uint32_t and uint8_t respectively. I am not sure how to declare the functions such that it returns uint32_t and also what to do with the pointer uint8_t *buf. Please help me in figuring out on how to convert the function, from C++ to python.

This is my C++ code:

```cpp
uint32_t Functions::Do_calc(uint8_t *buf, uint32_t len){
    return Do_calc(25, buf, len);
}

uint32_t Functions::Do_calc(uint32_t val, uint8_t *buf, uint32_t len){
    uint32_t temp_int, c = val;
    uint32_t ip_buf[128];
    uint32_t j, rem = 0, tf = 0, p = 0;

    rem = len;
    while(rem > 0){
        if(rem <= 512){
            tf = rem;
        }
        else{
            tf = 512;
        }

        for(j = 0; j < 128; j++){
            ip_buf[j]=0;
        }

        for(j = 0; j < tf; j += 2){
            temp = ((buf[p * 512 + (j + 3)]<<24) +
                (buf[p * 512 + (j + 2)]<<16) +
                (buf[p * 512 + (j + 1)]<<8) +
                buf[p * 512 + j]);
            ip_buf[j / 4] = temp;
        }

        c = c_cal(ip_buf, tf, c, 0x04C22AB9, 2, true);
        p++
    }

    return c;
}


uint32_t Functions::c_cal(uint32_t *d_base, uint32_t d_size, uint32_t c, uint32_t poly, uint8_t c_size, bool b_r_ip)
{
    unsigned long d_offset;
    unsigned long d, d_temp;
    unsigned char c_bit;

    d = 0;
    for(d_offset = 0; d_offset < d_size; (d_offset += c_size))
    {
        u32_d_temp = 0;
        d_temp = d_base[d_offset/c_size];
        if(FALSE == b_r_ip)
        {
            d = d_temp;
        }
        else
        {
            d = 0;
            for(c_bit = 0; c_bit < (c_size << 3); c_bit++)
            {
                d <<= 1;
                d |= (d_temp & 1);
                d_temp >>= 1;
            }
        }

        for(c_bit = 0; c_bit < (c_size << 3); c_bit++)
        {
            if(((c >> ((c_size << 3) - 1)) ^ d) & 1)
            {
                c <<= 1;
                d >>= 1;
                c ^= poly;
            }
            else
            {
                c <<= 1;
                d >>= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return (c & (0xFFFFFFFF >> (32 - (c_size << 3))));
}
```

This is my attempted Python implementation. As you can see I just did a basic implementation as I did not worry about the pointer and the size of the integer which is very much needed:

```
def Do_calc(buf, len):
    return Do_calc(0, buf, len)

def Do_calc(val, buf, len):
    ip_buf = []
    c = val
    p = 0
    rem = len

    while rem > 0:
        if rem <= 512:
            tf = rem
        else:
            tf = 512

        for j in range(128):
            ip_buf[j].append = 0

        for j in xrange(0, tf, 2):
            temp_int = ((buffer[packet * 512 + (i + 3)] << 24) +
                (buffer[packet * 512 + (i + 2)] << 16) +
                (buffer[packet * 512 + (i + 1)] << 8) +
                buffer[packet * 512 + i])
            ip_buf[j/4] = temp

        c = c_cal(ip_buf, tf, c, 0x04C22AB9, 2, true)
        p += 1
     

    return c
```

How do I properly do the conversion after taking care of all the aspects?

Comment: You can't set a list member that doesn't exist yet.  Either fill the list with dummy values or use `.append` to add new data.

Comment: Integers in Python can be any length at all, I wouldn't worry about the difference between `uint32_t` and any other `int`.

Comment: @MarkRansom For this problem it is important that I take care of the sizes

Comment: Why?  I don't see anything in the C++ code that relies on the size of the int.

Comment: @MarkRansom its a function that is doing a 32 bit CRC calculation so it matters. Otherwise we are not going to get the right value

Comment: The only place the size would matter would be in `c_cal`, but you didn't show that code so it's impossible to say what to do about it.

Comment: @MarkRansom I have added the c_cal function. Please help

Comment: Wow, that doesn't look like a terribly efficient way to do CRC.  And how can it possibly be accurate when it skips every other value?  I'm still not seeing anything that depends on the integer size, there are plenty of bit manipulations to put things in the proper place.

Comment: @MarkRansom Would you at least tell me how to change integer size in python? Please do not worry about the bit manipulations as they can be replicated easily. Just want to know how to declare the functions and integers like its done in C++ with uint32_t and how to take care of pointers. in python

Comment: I'm not telling you because there's simply no way to do it.  Integers in Python don't have a size.  And passing a list in Python is the same as passing a pointer in C++.